# GeoTools CollectionFeatureSource Disk Cleanup

Tags: geojson, geotools

I am using GeoTools to load a GeoJSON file into a PostGIS table.

My code looks like this:

```
        FeatureJSON featureJSON = new FeatureJSON();
        File geojsonFile = getFile(dataResource); // Loads the GeoJSON as a File
        SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = (SimpleFeatureCollection) featureJSON.readFeatureCollection(geojsonFile);
        SimpleFeatureType featureSchema = featureJSON.readFeatureCollectionSchema(geojsonFile, true);
        FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> geojsonFeatureSource = new CollectionFeatureSource(featureCollection);
```

Once I get the `geojsonFeatureSource` I can then use this to load the data into PostGIS using a `DataStore` object for PostGIS.

My problem occurs when I try to delete the GeoJSON file afterwards (held by the `geojsonFile` variable in my example). This file has a lock on it and cannot be deleted.

Now, when using previous Data Stores (such as Shapefiles) I am always able to call `.dispose()` on the `FeatureSource`. However, in this GeoJSON case, I am not able to call `.dispose()` on the `CollectionFeatureSource` because it is an "In Memory Data Store" - whatever that means.

My cleanup logic looks like:

```
            featureJSON = null;
            geojsonFeatureSource = null;
            featureCollection = null;
            featureSchema = null;
            geojsonFile.delete();
```

How can I get these objects to release their lock on the GeoJSON file so that I can clean up this input GeoJSON file?

Comment: Please consider using the geojson datastore instead of the featureSource

Comment: Are you referring to the OGR plugin?

Comment: No, there is a geoJSON datastore that acts just like all the other datastores

Comment: Can you please provide a link to that documentation?

Comment: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/New-unsupported-GeoJSON-datastore-now-available-td5243399.html

Comment: I see you are the author! Do you have any idea if/when this plugin will make it into the main repositories?

Comment: if it gets some tests, and users, or funding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to remove the lock when loading via a File object.

However, I am able to achieve the same level of functionality passing an InputStream into GeoTools, rather than passing in the File directly.

```
        FeatureJSON featureJSON = new FeatureJSON();
        InputStream geoJsonInputStream = getGeoJsonInputStream(dataResource);
        SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = (SimpleFeatureCollection) featureJSON.readFeatureCollection(geoJsonInputStream);
        FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> geojsonFeatureSource = new CollectionFeatureSource(featureCollection);
```

By never giving access to the File to GeoTools, a lock is never held. Once my logic is done, I can close the InputStream that I have passed to GeoTools, and then safely delete the original file.